# HTML Javascript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that keeps resetting every time I hit the required field when I click submit. Is there a way for my form to not submit or clear up when I hit the submit button, while checking for the required fields? My form alerts me, the submits. I don't know how to stop that, and make the alert go from one text type to the next. Like it checks the first input type, if it meets the requirements, then it checks for the next input type, is that possible?

```
<html>
<!--All my images were taken from google images-->
<!--4/29/2016-->
<title>LMC GYM</title>
</body>
<link rel= " stylesheet " type="text/css" href="Acss.css" />

<head>
  <script>
     function validate_form (){
        valid = true;
        var emailverify = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        var letter = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        var zip = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;
        if (emailverify.test(document.contact_form.contact_email.value) == false){
            alert ("Please put in a valid email provider.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_email.value ==""){
            alert ("Please put in your email.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_pass.value ==""){
            alert ("Please put in a password.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_pass1.value !=       document.contact_form.contact_pass.value){
            alert ("Please make sure passwords are the same.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_first.value ==""){
            alert ("Please put in your first name.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (letter.test(document.contact_form.contact_first.value) == false){
            alert ("No numbers! Please enter a valid first name.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_last.value ==""){
            alert ("Please put in your last name.");
            valid = false;
        }
       if (letter.test(document.contact_form.contact_last.value) == false){
           alert ("No numbers! Please enter a valid last name.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.contact_state.value ==""){
           alert ("Please enter state abbrevation, example New York-NY.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (letter.test(document.contact_form.contact_state.value) == false){
           alert ("Reminder no numbers! Please put in state abbrevation.");
           valid = false;
       }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_city.value ==""){
           alert ("Please put in your current city.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (letter.test(document.contact_form.contact_city.value) == false){
           alert ("Reminder no numbers! Please put in your current city.");
           valid = false;
       }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_add.value ==""){
           alert ("Please put in your address.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.contact_zip.value ==""){
           alert ("Please put in your zip code.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (zip.test(document.contact_form.contact_zip.value) == false){
           alert ("No letters in zip code!!.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.contact_phone.value ==""){
           alert ("Please put in your phone number.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (( document.contact_form.gen[0].checked == false) && (
document.contact_form.gen[1].checked == false )){
           alert ("Please choose your Gender: Male or Female");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.Membership.selectedIndex == 0){
           alert ("Please choose a membership.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (( document.contact_form.card[0].checked == false) && (document.contact_form.card[1].checked == false ) && (document.contact_form.card[2].checked == false ) && (document.contact_form.card[3].checked == false )){
           alert ("Please choose a card type");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.contact_cn.value ==""){
           alert ("Please put in your card number.");
           valid = false;
       }
       if (document.contact_form.contact_cvv.value ==""){
           alert ("Please put in your 3 digit cvv.");
           valid = false;
       }
       if (document.contact_form.Expmonth.selectedIndex == 0){
           alert ("Please choose a month on your credit card.");
           valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.Expyear.selectedIndex == 0){
          alert ("Please choose a year on your credit card.");
          valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.contact_date.value ==""){
          alert ("Please fill in the 'Expiration Date' box in the month and year format MMYY.");
          valid = false;
       }
      if (document.contact_form.terms.checked == false){
          alert ("Please check the Terms & Conditions box.");
          valid = false;
       }
      return false;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class= "contains">
    <div class ="head">
        <h4> LMC GYM </h4>
        <body   background="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/dumbbells_sports_gym_106546_3840x2 160.jpg">
        </h4>
     </div>
     <div class ="nav">
       <h5>Navigate</h5>
          <ul>
             <li><a href= "index.htm">Home</a></li>  
             </br> 
             <li><a href= "Package.htm">Offers</a></li>  
             </br>
             <li><a href= "Form.htm">Gym Form</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div><!--nav><-->
     <div class="chunk">
 </script>
</head>
   <form name="contact_form" method="post"  onSubmit="return validate_form ( );">
   <h1> Signup now to join the LMC GYM </h1>
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Account Information:</legend>
   E-mail: <input type="email" name="contact_email"> </br></br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="contact_pass"></br></br>
   Verify Password: <input type="password" name="contact_pass1"></br></br>
</fieldset>
  </br>

<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Information:</legend>

First Name: <input type="text" name="contact_first" maxlength="13"> </br></br>

Last Name: <input type="text" name="contact_last" maxlength="13"> </br></br>

State: <input type="text" name="contact_state" maxlength="2"> </br></br>

City: <input type="text" name="contact_city" maxlength="13"> </br></br>

Address: <input type="text" name="contact_add" maxlength="21"> </br></br>

Zip Code: <input type="number" name="contact_zip" maxlength="5" > </br></br>

Phone Number: <input type="number" name="contact_phone" maxlength="10" > </br>    </br>

Your Gender: <input type="radio" name="gen" value="Male"> Male
&nbsp; <input type="radio"name="gen" value="Female"> Female </br></br>
</fieldset> </br>


<fieldset>
<legend>Payment Information:</legend>

Membership: 
<select name="Membership" >
<option value="">Please choose an option:</option>
<option value= "Bronze "> Bronze </option>
<option value= "Silver"> Silver </option>
<option value= "Gold">Gold</option> </select> </br></br>

Card Type: <input type="radio" name="card" value="Mastercard"> Mastercard &nbsp;
&nbsp; <input type="radio"name="card" value="Visa"> Visa </br>
&nbsp; <input type="radio"name="card" value="American Express"> American Express     &nbsp;
&nbsp; <input type="radio"name="card" value="Discover"> Discover &nbsp; </br>    </br>


Card Number: <input type="number" name="contact_cn" maxlength="16"> </br></br>

Card CVV: <input type="number" name="contact_cvv" min="009" maxlength="3"> </br></br>

Good Through: 
<select name="Expmonth" >
<option value=""> Month:</option>
<option value= "01 "> 01 </option>
<option value= "02 "> 02 </option>
<option value= "03"> 03 </option>
<option value= "04">04</option>
<option value= "05 "> 05 </option>
<option value= "06"> 06 </option>
<option value= "07">07</option>
<option value= "08"> 08 </option>
<option value= "09">09</option>
<option value= "10"> 10 </option>
<option value= "11"> 11 </option>
<option value= "12">12</option> </select> &nbsp;


<select name="Expyear" >
<option value=""> Year:</option>
<option value= "18 "> 18 </option>
<option value= "19 "> 19 </option>
<option value= "20"> 20 </option>
<option value= "21">21</option>
<option value= "22 "> 22 </option>
<option value= "23"> 23 </option>
<option value= "24">24</option>
<option value= "25"> 25 </option>
<option value= "26">26</option>
<option value= "27"> 27 </option>
<option value= "28"> 28 </option>
<option value= "29">29</option> </select> </br></br>

</fieldset>

Do you agree to the Terms and Conditions?</br></br>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="Yes"> Yes

</br></br>

<p><input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit"></p> 
<p><input type="reset" name="reset"></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>




</div><!--"chunk"><-->

<div class="foot">
</div><!--foot><-->

</div><!--contains><-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely you meant `return valid;` rather than `return false;`

Comment: Your HTML is badly formatted. `contact_date` doesn't exist in your form which results in JS runtime error and thus form submission without proper validation. As a side note, prospects hate alerts.

Comment: BTW, what is `</br>`? Looks like an attempt at faux XHTML `<br />`, which is a hangover from about 10 years ago. Just use `<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

event.preventDefault(); prevents default behaviour (duh), which doesn't refresh the page.

I would use the following piece of code:

```
function validate_form(){
    //
    //
    //
}    
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    validate_form();
}
```

But, as [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) suggested, this would prevent the default submission routine as well. So you should explicitly add a call to submit function (or the form's submit method, if you are using it), e.g.

```
event.preventDefault();
if(validate_form()){
    form.submit()
} else { /*error handling routine*/ }
```

Or you could do it in one line like this (doesn't make sense with default submit, since it would be implementing the default behaviour anyway):

```
event.preventDefault();
return validate_form() && my_submit_nethod();
// form submits only if validate_form evaluated to true
```

Or, just return the validation result and leave the form to submit. Note, that currently, if the validation returns `true`, your page **will** refresh.

```
return validate_form();
```

Finally, another thing you could do is change the form's submission method:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
function my_submit_routine(){
    // here goes your code for submitting
};
form.submit = my_submit_routine;
```

Comment: Why prevent default before the form has been validated? The validation function just needs to return false to stop submission (as the OP does already).

Comment: @RobG I'd say, that since all we are doing is validating the form anyway, it makes little difference, if any, if we put the `e.preventDefault()` after the validation call. Naturally, if there is a dfference, I would be grateful to hear about it - live and learn.

Comment: If you call *preventDefault* then you've stopped the form from submitting, regardless of the outcome of validation. You must then manually call the form's submit method to submit it, so `if (validate_form()) {form.submit()} else {/*validation failed*/}` vs `return validate_form()`.

Comment: Where should I put the event.preventDefault? Its seems not to work, what should I do for it to get the form to start working, like what needs to be replaced? I'm sorry I am just not good at this.

Comment: @MLowt You need  to select the form HTMLElement ( make sure, you are running your script after the DOM has been constructed, i.e. after the html). Then add the eventListener to the form element. In the function you pass to the addEventListener you should type: `event.preventDefault(); return validate_form() && form.submit();` This should refresh the page if the form passed validation, and will NOT refresh the page if validation fails.

Comment: @MLowt if you don't wont the page to refresh at all, then just don't type the `form.submit()` thing. Just `preventDefault()` and then `validate_form()`